# Confusion regarding boundary map between simplicial complexes and orientation

Tags: algebraic-topology

For some reason the following point has always caused me some level of confusion: consider a simplicial complex $G$ and the boundary map on the complex, $\partial_k : C_k \to C_{k-1}$, often represented by a matrix and called the $k$th incidence matrix.

Why is that the entry $\partial_k[r,f]$ of the matrix (corresponding to a $(k-1)$-face $r$ and a $k$ face $f$, defined to be $(-1)^j$ if $f=\{v_0,v_1, \dots, v_k\}$ with $v_0<\cdots <v_k$ and $r=f\setminus \{v_j\}$ for some $j$, and $0$ otherwise) is precicely $-1$ when the orientation differs and $1$ if it matches (assuming we imagine the standard orientation in the complex $G$)?

In particular, how come removing an odd-indexed vertex from $f$ above implies the orientations don't match between $r$ and $f$? I seem to be having some trouble seeing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to see why we would use alternating sums via the map $\partial_1:C_1\to C_0$, i.e. the map sending lines to vertices, and then it should be clear that the parity of the vertex is not as important as the fact that the boundary map must be expressed in terms of an alternating sum. Suppose we are looking at a triangle (or a 2-simplex), with vertices $v_0,v_1,v_2$. Then, $C_1=\mathbb{Z}\Big\{\{v_0,v_1\},\{v_1,v_2\},\{v_2,v_0\}\Big\}$, where the line $\{v_i,v_j\}$ represents the line that begins at $v_i$ and ends at $v_j$
. Now, the boundary map formula tells us that
$$\partial_1(\{v_0,v_1\})+\partial_1(\{v_1,v_2\})+\partial_1(\{v_2,v_0\})=v_1-v_0+v_2-v_1+v_0-v_2=0
$$
The fact that the sum is zero tells us that these lines form the boundary of a shape that is a dimension higher (i.e. the face of the triangle). In fact, any element $[f]\in C_n$ such that $\partial_n[f]=0$ is called a boundary. The only way that the sum could equal zero was because it was alternating. If we defined the boundary map by instead negating when we removed even terms, then the above sum would still be $0$. This idea will still hold in higher dimensions, i.e, using parity of a vertex is a very natural way to define an alternating sum - that is why it is important.